# Start task, later wait for completion

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have a pretty intensive task, that I can run at the beginning of a function, but I then need the result at a later point in the function.

The function takes a few seconds to complete and there is no reason not to let the task run earlier. Do other processing in between, to then wait a shorter amount of time for the completion.

`analyzer.Parse()` is a `Task<IAnalyzerResult>`.

```
analyzer = new ExprAnalyzer(expr);
//start the task
analyzer.Parse().Start();

// [...] Do other stuff

// Now I need analyzer.Parse() to have finished
IAnalyzerResult res = await analyzer.Parse() //this obviously doesn't work.

// [...] Process the result
```

How do I start a task and then wait for it to complete at another point in time. Simply calling `await analyzer.Parse();` wont do the trick.

I read how to do it somewhere years ago, but I couldn't find anything on Google and Stackoverflow anymore.

Comment: `Task<IAnalyzerResult> analyzerTask = analyzer.Parse().Start(); ... IAnalyzerResult res = await analyzerTask;`

Comment: Please do not [edit answers to change the results](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58937480/revisions). If you think there is an issue with the answer, write a comment. Also [you're wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937433/start-task-later-wait-for-completion/58937480#comment104133708_58937480)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the returned Task:

```
Task<IAnalyzerResult> t = analyzer.Parse();
```

Then, await its result:

```
IAnalyzerResult res = await t;
```

Comment: For clarity about all the edits on this: not only is `Start()` unnecessary here, but it will throw an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "Start may not be called on a promise-style task." Try it :) The only time you need to call `Start()` is if you create the `Task` with `new Task()`.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I bet that the `ExprAnalyzer.Parse` returns a cold `Task`. The OP doesn't seem to be experienced with async/await and the TPL in general, so they probably don't know that creating cold tasks is considered an oddity nowadays. They may not even be aware about the difference between hot and cold tasks.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Very true. But yeah, it would be a weird thing to do.